# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un string a un input de un codigo de cmd por medio de bat?

Tags: mysql, cmd, batch, .bat, mysqldump

lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un archivo .bat para hacer backup de mysql el cual contiene:

```
cd C:/xampp/mysql/bin 
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases  > backup.sql
```

Como sabrán pedirá la contraseña pero necesito que esta se agregue automáticamente y no se requiera escribir nada, simplemente abrir el archivo para que se ejecute pero cuando le doy click muestra el campo de "Enter password:" como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: Vista de lo que manda el archivo]

¿sabe cómo podría pasarle la contraseña desde el mismo código sin necesidad de digitarla y darle enter? gracias de antemano:D

Comment: Intenta con `-pTuContraseña`, sin espacio después de "p".

Comment: Muchas gracias jaja literal si era solo por ello, creí que el espacio no afectaba al colocar la contraseña y por eso no la detectaba.